# How to make (or event fake) ripple animation on iPhone, iPad by UIView!

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation

I'm doing an app on iPad, and I wanna make a ripple effect in a background image, just the ripple animation for surface of water. Flash can solve this issue easily, but it's not available on iPad. Does anyone know something about this?

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 5, Apple now has a sample project called [GLCameraRipple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html) that lets you tap/draw on the screen to create animated water ripples over incoming video from the camera... a nice example of using OpenGL ES 2.0 and GLKit.